# Displaying an image with pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, blit

I am having a problem with displaying an image in pygame. The image is in the same directory/folder but it still has an error. This error popped out of the blue and I'm not sure how to fix it... My code below

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.constants import QUIT
pygame.init()
GameSprite = pygame.image.load('GameSprite.png')
GameSprite = pygame.transform.scale(GameSprite,(200, 200))
def main():
    x = 100
    y = 100
    velocity = 0
    velocity = pygame.Vector2()
    velocity.xy = 3, 0
    acceleration = 0.1
    DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((570, 570))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird Related Game")
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
    while True: 
        DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
        #pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE,(x,y,50,50))
        DISPLAY.blit(GameSprite,(x,y))
        y += velocity.y
        x += velocity.x
        velocity.y += acceleration
        if x + 50 > DISPLAY.get_width():
            velocity.x = -3
        if x < 0:
            velocity.x = 3
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                velocity.y = -4.2
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(10)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not sufficient to copy the image files in the project directory. You also need to set the working directory.
The image file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The  working directory can be different to the directory of the python script.
The name and path of the script file can be retrieved with [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). The current working directory can be set with [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).
Add the following lines of code at the beginning of your script to set the working directory to the same as the script's directory:

```py
import os
import pygame, sys
from pygame.constants import QUIT

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

pygame.init()
GameSprite = pygame.image.load('GameSprite.png')
```

Comment: @DevAndra Just put it at the begin of your script. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make things simpler instead of writing "GameSprite.png" try adding the path to the file.
Example:
if the GameSprite.png is in the location C://Users/person/Desktop

Replace `GameSprite = pygame.image.load('GameSprite.png')`
with
`GameSprite = pygame.image.load('C://Users/person/Desktop/GameSprite.png')`

Just put the file location in `pygame.image.load()`